# Django form.is_valid() is skipped and return false

Tags: python, django

My form doesn't read the is_valid() part.
In the terminal it returns:

"POST /app/contact/send_/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0

"GET /app/contact/send_/fail/ HTTP/1.1" 200 4648

I tried to typed random words inside the form.is_valid(), still returns the same as above.

It won't allow to successfully send the information to destined email address.

I don't know what I have missed. Any help is great. Thank you

My Models.py

```
class MessageForm(models.Model):
CATEGORY = (
    ('B', 'Business inquiry',),
    ('C', 'Career opportunity',),
    ('G', 'General inquiry',),

)
name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
email = models.EmailField(max_length=200)
phone = models.CharField(max_length=200)
category = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=CATEGORY)
text = models.TextField()
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from .models import MessageForm

class MessagesForm(forms.ModelForm):
  class Meta:
    model = MessageForm
    fields = ['name','email','phone','category','text']
    labels = {
        'name': "Name",
        'email': "Email ",
        'phone': "Phone",
        'category': "Category",
        'text': "How can we help you with?"
    }
```

Views.py

```
from .forms import MessagesForm
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.core.mail import send_mail


def contact(request):
  if request.method == 'POST':
     form = MessagesForm(request.POST)
     if form.is_valid():
        name = form.cleaned_data['name']
        email = form.cleaned_data['email']
        phone = form.cleaned_data['phone']
        category = form.cleaned_data['category']
        text = form.cleaned_data['text']

        subject = [name, phone, category]
        form.save()
 
        send_mail(subject, text, email, [settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER], fail_silently=False)
        return redirect('success/', status='success')
     else:
        return redirect('fail/', status='fail')
 else:
     form = MessagesForm()


 context ={'form':form}

 return render(request, 'contact.html', context)
```

```
def success(request):
    return render(request,'deliver.html')

def fail(request):
    return render(request,'red.html')
```

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from .views import *
app_name = "app"

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^contact/$', contact, name='contact'),
    url(r'^contact/success/$', success, name='success'),
    url(r'^contact/fail/$', fail, name='fail'),
]
```

HTML

```
 <form method="post" class="php-email-form" action="{% url 'app:contact' %}" target="_blank">
       {%csrf_token%}
       {{form.as_p}}
       <button class="text-center mb-2" type="submit">Send Message</button>
 </form>
```

Comment: It does, in fact it returns a 302 which is a redirect, and then it makes thus a second request to the redirect.

Comment: Why your HTML page redirects to `sending_form` and you have given `contact` in views.py...?? which view do you want to hit...??

Comment: ah sorry, forgot to remove the action url. 
I want to hit the contact page